# in google colab imageio imread() gives me FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/example_dog.jpg'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-imageio

how I resolve it

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-56401e31a9d3> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 # Load the image
----> 5 image = io.imread('example_dog.jpg')
      6 
      7 # Convert the image to grayscale

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/imageio/core/request.py in _parse_uri(self, uri)
    405                 # Reading: check that the file exists (but is allowed a dir)
    406                 if not os.path.exists(fn):
--> 407                     raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
    408             else:
    409                 # Writing: check that the directory to write to does exist

FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/example_dog.jpg'
```

Comment: why do you think that this file should exist?